# How can I do string interpolation inside a doctest in Elixir?

Tags: testing, elixir

I've been trying out doctests in Elixir and it has been working out pretty well until I tried doing string interpolation.

Here is the code:

```
  @doc"""
  Decodes the user resource from the sub claim in the received token for authentication.

  ## Examples

      iex> attrs = %{email: "test@example.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password"}
      iex> {:ok, user} = Accounts.create_user(attrs)
      iex> resource_from_claims(%{"sub" => "User:#{user.id}"})
      {:ok, %User{}}

  """
  def resource_from_claims(%{"sub" => "User:" <> id}) do
    resource = Accounts.get_user(id)
    case resource do
      nil -> {:error, :no_result}
      _ -> {:ok, resource}
    end
  end
```

I get this error when running `mix test`:

> variable "user" does not exist and is being expanded to "user()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name

I can confirm that the `user` variable does exist and works on just about everything else unless I try to put it inside a string interpolation.

Is there another way to do string interpolation inside doctests?

**Edit**: It looks like I'm getting this error because the string interpolation part inside `@doc` is actually being run outside the scope of the doctest and instead being run as part of the module itself. I'm going to see if there's another way to do string interpolation in the context of the doctest.

Answer (score 2):

After posting an edit (see above), I found out that the solution is to call the `@doc` string with `~S`:

```
  @doc ~S"""
  Decodes the user resource from the sub claim in the received token for authentication.

  ## Examples

      iex> attrs = %{email: "test@example.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password"}
      iex> {:ok, user} = Accounts.create_user(attrs)
      iex> resource_from_claims(%{"sub" => "User:#{user.id}"})
      {:ok, %User{}}

  """
```

This way, the module will ignore any string interpolation written inside the `@doc` block which will allow the doctest to perform the string interpolation instead.

Reference: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/2512

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with a doctest itself; [`~S`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_S/2) sigil, unlike [`~s`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_s/2), prevents the interpolation on it’s own.

Comment: @mudasobwa How so? Without `~S`, the doctest fails because the module already does the interpolation which results in a compile error. I don't think `~s` would solve my problem since I need the doctest to do the interpolation instead.

Comment: I mean, you need to prevent the whole comment string from being interpolated. It does not matter, whether it’s a comment string, or a plain string somewhere in the codebase. `~S` **unlike** `~s` and **unlike** plain `"""`, prevents this interpolation. That’s it.